# Async Route Element Return in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Getting Error: Guard(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing.

I want to call the API in my guard component before returning the element to Route Element to check if the logged in user have access to specific route or not.

For that, I have implemented a guard. Here's the route file code.

```
export default function Router() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="organizations">
                <Route path="list" element={<Guard><ListOrganization /></Guard>} />
        </Routes >
    );
}
```

Guard component code

```
const Guard = (props) => {
    fetch('https://apiToCheckPermission.com')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.isPermission) {
            return props.children;
        }
    })
};

export default Guard;
```

It's kind of a thing that, I want to implement async route element. But React is throwing error if I don't immediately return the element from Guard.

Can anyone please tell How to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Guard` is supposed to be a React component then it needs to *always* return valid JSX. The `Guard` currently returns nothing. I.E. it would need to return something from the Promise chain *and then* return that from the function body.

To resolve use some local state to hold a confirmed/verified permission value and conditionally render the `children` prop or a fallback. A typical route protection implementation will wait to confirm a user's access then render either the `children` or redirect to the login page with the location being accessed so the user can be redirected back after authenticating.

Example:

```
const Guard = ({ children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = React.useState(); // <-- initially undefined

  React.useEffect(() => {
    );
    fetch('https://apiToCheckPermission.com')
      .then(response => {
        setHasPermission(response.isPermission);
      });
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator, spinner, etc
  }

  return hasPermission
    ? children
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
};
```

Comment: But that's not the async routing. I am returning another component until I got the response from API. I don't want to show another component to user.

Comment: @ChrisT What do you want to display to the user while the asynchronous code is running? In my example here I'm returning `null` to not render anything until the permission check completes. I'm not sure what you mean by "async routing", route matching and rendering is completely synchronous. React component rendering is completely synchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Try to define a state to handle the permission and `useEffect` to load the data:

```
const Guard = (props) => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPermission = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('https://apiToCheckPermission.com');
        setHasPermission(response.isPermission);
    }
    
    fetchPermission().catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  if (!hasPermission) return <>Unauthorized</>;

  return props.children;
};

export default Guard;
```

Comment: Are you importing `useState` and `useEffect`?

Comment: It depends on the structure of the response. Try to set `setHasPermission(response.isPermission);`

Comment: The `useEffect` hook callback ***absolutely cannot*** be an `async` function. This will implicitly return a Promise object that React will try to use as the `useEffect` hook's cleanup function. Just abstract the asynchronous callback into an inner function that is called in the callback, or declare it outside the `useEffect` hook and call in the callback.